# Refreshing logout the user from the page

Tags: php

I have a page which is refreshing every 10 sec.
When the page refreshing kicking the user out of the page and send him to auth.php.
With

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
header("location: auth.php");
exit;
}
```

I need this function to prevent direct access from the url.
But the problem the user get logout after refreshing, how to make this function false when refresh is done and else  prevent direct  access from url

My code as flow.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php


$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = 10;
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");



if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{

header("location: auth.php");
exit;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must used your headers BEFORE any HTML output. Otherwise it just will not work.

Comment: ok i'll do that.what i need how to prevent the user from getting logout after refresh.

Comment: The PHP documentation reads: "The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted." - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(!isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    {
        header("location: auth.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = 10;
    header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
    }
} 
else
{
    print "/*Error in refreshing*/";
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: first of all thank you for your code. your code is working the user didn't get logut out. refreshing fine. but when i access the page from url is opening with me. thats the problem one problem solved second not.!!! when i access from url i supposed to be redirect to auth.php but not happening.

Comment: @hadi then u can insert 'else if' statement into first 'if' statement.

Comment: then try the reverse. put parent statement in place of child and vice versa.

Comment: i did, refreshing fine but accessing the url not redirecting. do you have anther salutation. for that

Comment: I already figure it out 
With 

`<?php`
`session_start();`
`$_SESSION['valid'] = "yes";`
`echo "Page 1";`
`?>`

page2.php has this script:

`<?php`
`session_start();`
`if ($_SESSION['valid'] != "yes") header("Location: page1.php");`
`echo "Page 2";`
`?>`